# zsh bindkey ctrl-enter to autosuggest-accept using kitty

Tags: zsh, kitty

I want to set up `ctrl-enter` to accept zsh autosuggests. I've been trying `bindkey "\C-\r" autosuggest-accept` but this ends up as being understood as just pressing enter (and thus overriding `accept-line` making it pretty hard to do anything :)). I'm using `kitty` and with `kitty` it was possible to do that with `ble.sh` autosuggestions in bash, so I'm hoping it is also possible in zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\C-\r` is not traditionally a thing in terminal land, because it is not a valid [ASCII control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart). As a consequence, in most terminals, unless configured otherwise, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> outputs the same as <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or even nothing at all).

`ble.sh`, however, puts Kitty into a [special XTerm mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-gt-Pp;Pv-m.1EB3) that enables combinations of modifier keys that traditionally don’t produce (different) output. I don’t know if there exists an equivalent of `ble.sh` for Zsh, but it would be feasible to write one. In a nutshell, here’s what such a script (or plugin, if you will) would need to do:

1. Add new keybindings for all existing keybindings that produce different output under this special mode.
2. Whenever the [Zsh Line Editor (ZLE)](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Special-Widgets) initializes, enable this mode:

   ```bash
   autoload -Uz add-zle-hook-widget
   modify-other-keys-extended() {
     print -n '\e[>4;2m'
   }
   add-zle-hook-widget line-init \
       modify-other-keys-extended
   ```
3. Whenever the ZLE finishes, disable this mode:

   ```bash
   modify-other-keys-off() {
     print -n '\e[>4;0m'
   }
   add-zle-hook-widget line-finish \
       modify-other-keys-off
   ```

Comment: `ble.sh` puts the terminal in a [special mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-gt-Pp;Pv-m.1EB3) (`\e[>4;2m`) where some key presses with modifier sends escape sequences. Doing the same with `zsh`'s line editor would mean rebinding many ctrl / alt... keys.

Comment: Ah, so it's probably not possible anyway

Comment: It _is_ possible, but you would have to write a script that rebinds existing keybindings to the new set of escape codes. Definitely feasible.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the explanation. I was aware of XTerm’s special input mode, but I didn’t know anything about `ble.sh`. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the snippets! I think I'll try it out when I have some time on my hands to see what it breaks and how involved this would be :)